# Text File Number Holder isn't working, how do I fix it?

Tags: java, eclipse, file

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NC {

static Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args){

    File FileNumberChanger = new File("C:/Users/Michael/Desktop/FileNumberChanger.txt");

    try{

        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(FileNumberChanger);
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(FileNumberChanger);
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

        String numVText = br.readLine();
        int numVInt = 0;



        **if(numVText.equals("0")){ // Doesn't work
            numVInt = 0;
        }**
        if(numVText.equals("1")){
            numVInt = 1;
        }
        if(numVText.equals("2")){
            numVInt = 2;
        }
        if(numVText.equals("3")){
            numVInt = 3;
        }
        if(numVText.equals("4")){
            numVInt = 4;
        }
        if(numVText.equals("5")){
            numVInt = 5;
        }
        if(numVText.equals("6")){
            numVInt = 6;
        }
        if(numVText.equals("7")){
            numVInt = 7;
        }
        if(numVText.equals("8")){
            numVInt = 8;
        }
        if(numVText.equals("9")){
            numVInt = 9;
        }
        if(numVText.equals("10")){
            numVInt = 10;
        }
        if(numVText.equals("11")){
            numVInt = 11;
        }
        if(numVText.equals("12")){
            numVInt = 12;
        }
        if(numVText.equals("13")){
            numVInt = 13;
        }
        if(numVText.equals("14")){
            numVInt = 14;
        }
        if(numVText.equals("15")){
            numVInt = 15;
        }
        if(numVText.equals("16")){
            numVInt = 16;
        }
        if(numVText.equals("17")){
            numVInt = 17;
        }
        if(numVText.equals("18")){
            numVInt = 18;
        }
        if(numVText.equals("19")){
            numVInt = 19;
        }
        if(numVText.equals("20")){
            numVInt = 20;
        }
        if(numVText.equals("21")){
            numVInt = 21;
        }
        if(numVText.equals("22")){
            numVInt = 22;
        }
        if(numVText.equals("23")){
            numVInt = 23;
        }
        if(numVText.equals("24")){
            numVInt = 24;
        }
        if(numVText.equals("25")){
            numVInt = 25;
        }
        if(numVText.equals("26")){
            numVInt = 26;
        }
        if(numVText.equals("27")){
            numVInt = 27;
        }
        if(numVText.equals("28")){
            numVInt = 28;
        }
        if(numVText.equals("29")){
            numVInt = 29;
        }
        if(numVText.equals("30")){
            numVInt = 30;
        }
        if(numVText.equals("31")){
            numVInt = 31;
        }
        if(numVText.equals("32")){
            numVInt = 32;
        }
        if(numVText.equals("33")){
            numVInt = 33;
        }
        if(numVText.equals("34")){
            numVInt = 34;
        }
        if(numVText.equals("35")){
            numVInt = 35;
        }
        if(numVText.equals("36")){
            numVInt = 36;
        }
        if(numVText.equals("37")){
            numVInt = 37;
        }
        if(numVText.equals("38")){
            numVInt = 38;
        }
        if(numVText.equals("39")){
            numVInt = 39;
        }
        if(numVText.equals("40")){
            numVInt = 40;
        }
        if(numVText.equals("41")){
            numVInt = 41;
        }
        if(numVText.equals("42")){
            numVInt = 42;
        }
        if(numVText.equals("43")){
            numVInt = 43;
        }
        if(numVText.equals("44")){
            numVInt = 44;
        }
        if(numVText.equals("45")){
            numVInt = 45;
        }
        if(numVText.equals("46")){
            numVInt = 46;
        }
        if(numVText.equals("47")){
            numVInt = 47;
        }
        if(numVText.equals("48")){
            numVInt = 48;
        }
        if(numVText.equals("49")){
            numVInt = 49;
        }
        if(numVText.equals("50")){
            numVInt = 50;
        }
        if(numVText.equals("51")){
            numVInt = 51;
        }
        if(numVText.equals("52")){
            numVInt = 52;
        }
        if(numVText.equals("53")){
            numVInt = 53;
        }
        if(numVText.equals("54")){
            numVInt = 54;
        }
        if(numVText.equals("55")){
            numVInt = 55;
        }
        if(numVText.equals("56")){
            numVInt = 56;
        }
        if(numVText.equals("57")){
            numVInt = 57;
        }
        if(numVText.equals("58")){
            numVInt = 58;
        }
        if(numVText.equals("59")){
            numVInt = 59;
        }
        if(numVText.equals("60")){
            numVInt = 60;
        }
        if(numVText.equals("61")){
            numVInt = 61;
        }
        if(numVText.equals("62")){
            numVInt = 62;
        }
        if(numVText.equals("63")){
            numVInt = 63;
        }
        if(numVText.equals("64")){
            numVInt = 64;
        }
        if(numVText.equals("65")){
            numVInt = 65;
        }
        if(numVText.equals("66")){
            numVInt = 66;
        }
        if(numVText.equals("67")){
            numVInt = 67;
        }
        if(numVText.equals("68")){
            numVInt = 68;
        }
        if(numVText.equals("69")){
            numVInt = 69;
        }
        if(numVText.equals("70")){
            numVInt = 70;
        }
        if(numVText.equals("71")){
            numVInt = 71;
        }
        if(numVText.equals("72")){
            numVInt = 72;
        }
        if(numVText.equals("73")){
            numVInt = 73;
        }
        if(numVText.equals("74")){
            numVInt = 74;
        }
        if(numVText.equals("75")){
            numVInt = 75;
        }
        if(numVText.equals("76")){
            numVInt = 76;
        }
        if(numVText.equals("77")){
            numVInt = 77;
        }
        if(numVText.equals("78")){
            numVInt = 78;
        }
        if(numVText.equals("79")){
            numVInt = 79;
        }
        if(numVText.equals("80")){
            numVInt = 80;
        }
        if(numVText.equals("81")){
            numVInt = 81;
        }
        if(numVText.equals("82")){
            numVInt = 82;
        }
        if(numVText.equals("83")){
            numVInt = 83;
        }
        if(numVText.equals("84")){
            numVInt = 84;
        }
        if(numVText.equals("85")){
            numVInt = 85;
        }
        if(numVText.equals("86")){
            numVInt = 86;
        }
        if(numVText.equals("87")){
            numVInt = 87;
        }
        if(numVText.equals("88")){
            numVInt = 88;
        }
        if(numVText.equals("89")){
            numVInt = 89;
        }
        if(numVText.equals("90")){
            numVInt = 90;
        }
        if(numVText.equals("91")){
            numVInt = 91;
        }
        if(numVText.equals("92")){
            numVInt = 92;
        }
        if(numVText.equals("93")){
            numVInt = 93;
        }
        if(numVText.equals("94")){
            numVInt = 94;
        }
        if(numVText.equals("95")){
            numVInt = 95;
        }
        if(numVText.equals("96")){
            numVInt = 96;
        }
        if(numVText.equals("97")){
            numVInt = 97;
        }
        if(numVText.equals("98")){
            numVInt = 98;
        }
        if(numVText.equals("99")){
            numVInt = 99;
        }
        if(numVText.equals("100")){
            numVInt = 100;
        }

        System.out.println(numVInt);

        String usersFun = in.next();
        int usersInt = in.nextInt();

        if(usersFun.equals("set")){
            numVInt = usersInt;
        }
        if(usersFun.equals("add")){
            numVInt += usersInt;
        }
        if(usersFun.equals("take")){
            numVInt -= usersInt;
        }

        if(numVInt == 0){
            numVText = "0";
        }
        if(numVInt == 1){
            numVText = "1";
        }
        if(numVInt == 2){
            numVText = "2";
        }
        if(numVInt == 3){
            numVText = "3";
        }
        if(numVInt == 4){
            numVText = "4";
        }
        if(numVInt == 5){
            numVText = "5";
        }
        if(numVInt == 6){
            numVText = "6";
        }
        if(numVInt == 7){
            numVText = "7";
        }
        if(numVInt == 8){
            numVText = "8";
        }
        if(numVInt == 9){
            numVText = "9";
        }
        if(numVInt == 10){
            numVText = "10";
        }
        if(numVInt == 11){
            numVText = "11";
        }
        if(numVInt == 12){
            numVText = "12";
        }
        if(numVInt == 13){
            numVText = "13";
        }
        if(numVInt == 14){
            numVText = "14";
        }
        if(numVInt == 15){
            numVText = "15";
        }
        if(numVInt == 16){
            numVText = "16";
        }
        if(numVInt == 17){
            numVText = "17";
        }
        if(numVInt == 18){
            numVText = "18";
        }
        if(numVInt == 19){
            numVText = "19";
        }
        if(numVInt == 20){
            numVText = "20";
        }
        if(numVInt == 21){
            numVText = "21";
        }
        if(numVInt == 22){
            numVText = "22";
        }
        if(numVInt == 23){
            numVText = "23";
        }
        if(numVInt == 24){
            numVText = "24";
        }
        if(numVInt == 25){
            numVText = "25";
        }
        if(numVInt == 26){
            numVText = "26";
        }
        if(numVInt == 27){
            numVText = "27";
        }
        if(numVInt == 28){
            numVText = "28";
        }
        if(numVInt == 29){
            numVText = "29";
        }
        if(numVInt == 30){
            numVText = "30";
        }
        if(numVInt == 31){
            numVText = "31";
        }
        if(numVInt == 32){
            numVText = "32";
        }
        if(numVInt == 33){
            numVText = "33";
        }
        if(numVInt == 34){
            numVText = "34";
        }
        if(numVInt == 35){
            numVText = "35";
        }
        if(numVInt == 36){
            numVText = "36";
        }
        if(numVInt == 37){
            numVText = "37";
        }
        if(numVInt == 38){
            numVText = "38";
        }
        if(numVInt == 39){
            numVText = "39";
        }
        if(numVInt == 40){
            numVText = "40";
        }
        if(numVInt == 41){
            numVText = "41";
        }
        if(numVInt == 42){
            numVText = "42";
        }
        if(numVInt == 43){
            numVText = "43";
        }
        if(numVInt == 44){
            numVText = "44";
        }
        if(numVInt == 45){
            numVText = "45";
        }
        if(numVInt == 46){
            numVText = "46";
        }
        if(numVInt == 47){
            numVText = "47";
        }
        if(numVInt == 48){
            numVText = "48";
        }
        if(numVInt == 49){
            numVText = "49";
        }
        if(numVInt == 50){
            numVText = "50";
        }
        if(numVInt == 51){
            numVText = "51";
        }
        if(numVInt == 52){
            numVText = "52";
        }
        if(numVInt == 53){
            numVText = "53";
        }
        if(numVInt == 54){
            numVText = "54";
        }
        if(numVInt == 55){
            numVText = "55";
        }
        if(numVInt == 56){
            numVText = "56";
        }
        if(numVInt == 57){
            numVText = "57";
        }
        if(numVInt == 58){
            numVText = "58";
        }
        if(numVInt == 59){
            numVText = "59";
        }
        if(numVInt == 60){
            numVText = "60";
        }
        if(numVInt == 61){
            numVText = "61";
        }
        if(numVInt == 62){
            numVText = "62";
        }
        if(numVInt == 63){
            numVText = "63";
        }
        if(numVInt == 64){
            numVText = "64";
        }
        if(numVInt == 65){
            numVText = "65";
        }
        if(numVInt == 66){
            numVText = "66";
        }
        if(numVInt == 67){
            numVText = "67";
        }
        if(numVInt == 68){
            numVText = "68";
        }
        if(numVInt == 69){
            numVText = "69";
        }
        if(numVInt == 70){
            numVText = "70";
        }
        if(numVInt == 71){
            numVText = "71";
        }
        if(numVInt == 72){
            numVText = "72";
        }
        if(numVInt == 73){
            numVText = "73";
        }
        if(numVInt == 74){
            numVText = "74";
        }
        if(numVInt == 75){
            numVText = "75";
        }
        if(numVInt == 76){
            numVText = "76";
        }
        if(numVInt == 77){
            numVText = "77";
        }
        if(numVInt == 78){
            numVText = "78";
        }
        if(numVInt == 79){
            numVText = "79";
        }
        if(numVInt == 80){
            numVText = "80";
        }
        if(numVInt == 81){
            numVText = "81";
        }
        if(numVInt == 82){
            numVText = "82";
        }
        if(numVInt == 83){
            numVText = "83";
        }
        if(numVInt == 84){
            numVText = "84";
        }
        if(numVInt == 85){
            numVText = "85";
        }
        if(numVInt == 86){
            numVText = "86";
        }
        if(numVInt == 87){
            numVText = "87";
        }
        if(numVInt == 88){
            numVText = "88";
        }
        if(numVInt == 89){
            numVText = "89";
        }
        if(numVInt == 90){
            numVText = "90";
        }
        if(numVInt == 91){
            numVText = "91";
        }
        if(numVInt == 92){
            numVText = "92";
        }
        if(numVInt == 93){
            numVText = "93";
        }
        if(numVInt == 94){
            numVText = "94";
        }
        if(numVInt == 95){
            numVText = "95";
        }
        if(numVInt == 96){
            numVText = "96";
        }
        if(numVInt == 97){
            numVText = "97";
        }
        if(numVInt == 98){
            numVText = "98";
        }
        if(numVInt == 99){
            numVText = "99";
        }
        if(numVInt == 100){
            numVText = "100";
        }
        if(numVInt > 100){
            numVText = "100";
        }




        bw.close();
        br.close();
        fw.close();
        fr.close();

    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }



    }
```

Why doesn't this work?
I'm trying to get Strings with the value of numbers(by saying String ex = "0") from files, and then see the value and turn them into Integers. I have no idea how to solve this problem. Please Help.

By the way, I'm using eclipse, if that has anything to do with it. The problem is it's catching an exception coming from here:

```
if(numVText.equals("0")){
                numVInt = 0;
            }
```

Comment: My eyes're bleeding when I look at all these `if`s

Comment: wow... please, take a look at [Integer#parseInt](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt-java.lang.String-) and replace all these ifs

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the horrendous amount of `if` statements, use the following instead:

```
int result = Integer.parseInt(inputString);
```

To convert back, use:

```
String decimalNumber = Integer.toString(someInt);
```

---

How that you have included what's wrong with your code: I can only assume you are getting a `java.lang.NullPointerException`. In this case, the variable `numVInt` is `null` - you try to call a method on it, but it's `null`, so you get this exception.

From the official documentation of [`BufferedReader.readLine()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine--):

> Reads a line of text. A line is considered to be terminated by any one
>   of a line feed (`\n`), a carriage return (`\r`), or a carriage return
>   followed immediately by a linefeed.
>
> **Returns:** A String containing the
>   contents of the line, not including any line-termination characters,
>   or `null` if the end of the stream has been reached
>
> **Throws:** [`IOException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/IOException.html) - If an I/O error occurs

So the variable being `null` indicates that the end of the file has been reached: You should check for the `null` value before going on, like this (fully fixed code, it compiles, but untested):

```
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NC
{

    private static final Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception // You might need to handle exceptions better
    {
        File fileNumberChanger = new File("C:/Users/Michael/Desktop/FileNumberChanger.txt");

        int numVInt = -1;

        try(FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fileNumberChanger);
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr))
        {
            String gottenLine = br.readLine();
            if (gottenLine == null)
            {
                System.err.println("File does not contain a single line!");
                return;
            }
            numVInt = Integer.parseInt(gottenLine); // Might throw NumberFormatException if number is in invalid format
            System.out.println("Current number: " + numVInt);

            String usersFun = in.next();
            int usersInt = in.nextInt();

            switch(usersFun)
            {
                case "set":
                    numVInt = usersInt;
                    break;
                case "add":
                    numVInt += usersInt;
                    break;
                case "take":
                    numVInt -= usersInt;
                default:
                    System.err.println("Invalid user command!");
                    return; // End program
            }
            System.out.println("New number: " + numVInt);
        }

        try(FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fileNumberChanger);
            OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fos, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(osw))
        {
            // This will completely overwrite the file!
            bw.write(Integer.toString(numVInt));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm a little confused (As you could probably tell, I'm very in experienced) about the `Integer.parseInt(inputString);`  Could you please explain? Otherwise thank you.

Comment: @MichaelCasteel `Integer` is a class, just like `String` or `Scanner`. It contains the static method `parseInt` which converts a decimal integer in a string into an `int`. For example `Integer.parseInt("12354")` would return an `int` with the value `12354` which you can then calculate with (or use in any mathematic context or whereever a `int` is needed).

Comment: Ok, so its basically doing what all those 'if' statements were doing, but better? Is that its only use?(Not saying it isn't useful)

Comment: @MichaelCasteel Exactly. Also, not trying to be rude, but you can when in doubt look at the Java API documentation at anytime [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/) (Just search for your class in the bottom left section, click on it and find the relevant method, you will often get a very detailed explanation about what it does)